# GitHub: How can I transfer a repo that I own to an organization I own and keep it on my private account?

Tags: github

I have read the [help page](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/administering-a-repository/transferring-a-repository) and I have managed to transfer it to my organization but it is then **myorg/repo** rather than **myuser/repo**. I can create a new repo as my org which is **myuser/repo** though so there must be some way to transfer it like that, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a two options:

- Fork the repo (won't be private though)
- Clone the repo:

```
    git clone <repo url>

    cd <repo directory>

    git add . && git commit -m "<commit message>"

    git push origin <branch>
```

Cloning it is the only way to have the same repo but private.